# How best to terminate two high efficiency systems

Tags: hvac

I have a high efficiency gas furnace and a high-efficiency gas water heater. How best should I terminate intake and exhaust.?  Are termination kits available that would accommodate all four pipes?   Is it possible to join the two exhaust together and two intake pipes Together prior to exiting the wall in two single pipes?

Comment: What do you mean by "terminating"?

Comment: Provide the make and model of each. Depending on local codes, you may be able to join the dual exhaust ducts to a single larger duct. Ive seen it done on larger commercial units. Of course, the larger duct would have to be sized to double, or a value which is listed in the units manual if permissible. Lastly, local codes might override that ability even if permitted by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* you have a high-efficiency water heater? If you didn't pay about $1500 or more for the unit itself, you have a low-efficiency water heater, and the distinction is important because you can only use plastic pipe for the exhaust ducting with high-efficiency condensing gas-burning equipment. Anything less than 90% efficiency needs metal exhaust ducting. and special clearances to combustible materials (like plastic pipe) due to the high pipe wall temperature.

Your level of confusion as well as the dangerous nature of what you are asking about leads me to worry that there is a nonzero chance that you will blow yourself up or set fire to your house. If you insist on continuing the work, I would recommend that you read the gas plumbing and venting code in your municipality and follow the guidelines set forth there.

If you choose not to do this and continue with this as a DIY job, please understand the risks to life, limb, and financial livelihood posed by unsafe gas work.